# Block with .htaccess if url contains X

Tags: .htaccess

Because of large amount of spammers (With Adsense clickbombing...), I want to block them with htaccess.
Each link "visited" by spam bot are made is this way :
http://mywebsite.com/mypage/**?clickid=NUMBER**

The number is different for each visit.

So I want to deny access if url contains **?clickid=**

I tried this but it's not working because there is a question mark :

```
RewriteRule clickid - [F]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^clickid
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```